# See if there is statistically significant difference between two periodograms, in time series

Tags: time-series

I'm doing a research about some fishes in two different zones, < 9 meters and >= 9 meters and I'm working with time series. I did two periodograms for each zone. Now, I would like to compare them and see if there is some statistically significant difference between these two periodograms.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking around I found the paper,

[Ramirez et al. (2018) Testing Equality of Multiple Power Spectral Densities,](http://gpsc.uvigo.es/sites/default/files/publications/TestingEqualityPSDMatricesIEEETSP18.pdf)

which appears to deal with the problem you are interested in. Also, a good resource for stochastic properties of Fourier transforms and the periodogram is the book by D.R.Brillinger, *Time Series. Data Analysis and Theory*, HRW, 1979.